# Mat-autocomplete not showing in modal

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with using mat-autocomplete in bootstrap modal.
I have used below css but still have problem:)

```
.cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-overlay-pane { z-index: 9999 !important; }

.pac-container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Add it in your scss or css file  :

```
/deep/ .cdk-overlay-container { z-index: 9999; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try you can ::ng-deep in your css file

Comment: I tried that but it did not work . I have 2 autocomplete and I think that makes problem